# Create/delete a .txt file in a python program

Tags: python, if-statement, text

I have created a program to grab values from a text file. As you can see, depending on the value of the results, I have an if/else statement printing out the results of the scenario.

My problem is I want to set the code up so that the if statement creates a simple .txt file called data.txt to the C:\Python\Scripts directory.

In the event the opposite is true, I would like the else statement to delete this .txt file if it exists.

I'm a novice programmer and anything I've looked up or tried hasn't worked for me, so any help or assistance would be hugely appreciated.

```
import re

x = open("test.txt","r")
california = x.readlines(11)
dublin = x.readlines(125)

percentage_value = [float(re.findall('\d+\.\d+(?=\%)|\d+\.\d+(?=\s\%)', i[-1])[0]) for i in [california, dublin]]

print(percentage_value)

if percentage_value[0] <= percentage_value[1]:
    print('Website is hosted in Dublin')
else:
    print('Website is hosted in California')
x.close()
```

Comment: why can't you try `open("data.txt","w+")` in if statement for creating a file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you can set the path where the file should be written to by simply adding it to the filename, while you can remove the file by using the os package:

```
import os 
filename = 'C:\Python\Scripts\data.txt' 

if percentage_value[0] <= percentage_value[1]:
    fileout = open(filename, 'w')
else:
    if os.path.exists(filename): os.remove(filename)
```

Comment: Better - just `os.remove()` and ignore the exception if you get one. The `exists` doesn't tell you much, because the file may be removed in between those statements.